# making simple non-asynchronous post request in c# in 2021

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm trying to write some very simple code in C# that makes one HTTPS post request and returns the result, and I'm a bit confused on which library to use. Since my code only needs to run one HTTPS request, I do not need any async and I feel like it would be simpler to go without it.

It seems like System.Net.Http.HttpClient was not built for non-async uses, whereas System.Net.WebRequest has warnings all over the documentation about how it is deprecated and I should use HttpClient instead. The vast majority of tutorials and StackOverflow questions for WebRequest end up being 5+ or even 10+ years old.

Can someone point me to a good tutorial or library for my use case in the year 2021?

Comment: "Since my code only needs to run one HTTPS request, I do not need any async" -> running one or a hundred requests makes no difference. IO code is asynchronous, regardless of you using the TPL or not. The HttpClient is completely asynchronous so that people aren't mistaken in how it works

Comment: "_I feel like it would be simpler to go without it_" -> it isn't. Unless you _need_ sync behaviour, use `HttpClient` and its async methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use HttpClient for this. It has a synchronous Send method which you can use

```
var client = new HttpClient();
            
    var webRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://your-api.com")
    {
        Content = new StringContent("{ 'some': 'value' }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };

    var response = client.Send(webRequest);

    using var reader = new StreamReader(response.Content.ReadAsStream());
            
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'Send'`. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: It has been added in .NET 5.0 . Please check which you are using. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/34948

Comment: Do you know if it was ever added to .NET Framework? I had a hard time with some dll imports with .NET 5.0

Comment: I am not sure for .NET framework. For me also if I use .NET framework, it is not recognizing the Send method

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be good to go with [System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Send(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.send?view=net-6.0)

This function is not asynchronous.

Though, using the async functions isn't really any hassle either. They just return a Task. If you access the Result property of the returned Task, the thread will automatically wait for the task to complete. So bascially it will process the request synchronisouly.